# Minecraft Name Changed and Can't Undo

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft Gamertag (under Settings/Profile/Gamertag) changed from Steve to one of the autofill random names (tonedketchup613).  This random name was what came up when I recently signed on to Xbox and created a profile to play on the servers.  I changed the random Xbox name to my own homemade name, but somehow my Minecraft game still has the random name tonedketchup613 as the Gamertag.

I tried the button "Edit Gamertag", but that just takes me to Xbox which properly reflects my homemade name.  I logged into my Mojang account and that has a completely different homemade name/profile and is fine.

How do I edit the name showing under Settings/Profile which shows when I play Minecraft (not on the external Xbox servers), but locally?

(Note: I seem to have 3 Minecraft related names...  Minecraft Game, Mojang, and Xbox - I need help with the first.)

Answer (score 1):

## Syncing

Sign out and back in into Minecraft. This should resync the account and that will hopefully fix any name errors.

Comment: How is this supposed to change his Minecraft name? You should avoid the one-line answer, as it is low quality and usually don't give a full answer, as here.

Comment: @Zoma this is a good quality answer, and it should change your Minecraft name. Changing his XBox name is not the issue and this should sync them together.

Comment: @Penguin that's exactly why one line answer should be avoided, it doesn't explain at all how the problem will be solved. To me, your comment's more usefull than the answer itslef, as it explain how the problem is solved, and it let you have hint on where to search if this still don't resolve the problem.

Comment: @Zoma okay fair

Answer (score 0):

It's in Settings/Profile. If it has a text box, you aren't signed in properly and may need to redownload Minecraft.